# Get links from table php

Tags: php, html

how to get links from table and save it in file.txt with php :

```
<TABLE width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed">
                    <TR>                
                        <TD width="15"></TD>
                        <TD width="570" valign="top">

                            <TABLE width="570" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed">
                            <TR>

                            <TD width="190" valign="top">

                                <TABLE width="190" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed">



                                        <TR height="98">
                                            <TD width="190" align="center" valign="top"><A HREF="http://mylink.com/1" class="opacityit"><IMG SRC="http://mylink.com/1/784.jpg" title="test1" title="test1" BORDER=0 style="cursor:hand" /></A></TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR height="2">
                                            <TD width="190"></TD>
                                        </TR>

                                        <TR>
                                            <TD width="190" align="center" Class="text6"><A HREF="http://mylink.com/1" class="Link8" title="test1"><h2 style="color:#000"><font size=2>test1</font></h2></A></TD>
                                        </TR>

                                </TABLE>

                            </TD>
```

```
                                <TABLE width="190" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed">

                                        <TR height="98">
                                            <TD width="190" align="center" valign="top"><A HREF="http://mylink.com/2" class="opacityit"><IMG SRC="http://mylink.com/2/784.jpg" title="test2" title="test2" BORDER=0 style="cursor:hand" /></A></TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR height="2">
                                            <TD width="190"></TD>
                                        </TR>

                                        <TR>
                                            <TD width="190" align="center" Class="text6"><A HREF="http://mylink.com/2" class="Link8" title="test2"><h2 style="color:#000"><font size=2>test2</font></h2></A></TD>
                                        </TR>

                                </TABLE>

                            </TD>
```

$html = file_get_contents($urlcontent);

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

// grab all the on the page
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//tr");



for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
$href = $hrefs->item($i);
$url = $href->getAttribute('href');

echo $url.'<br />';
}
```

how to get links from table and save it in file.txt with php

I only want to get the links of the table

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: There are several ways of doing it. At least show us where you get stuck.

Comment: I could not retrieve the links code not work ??

Answer (score 0):

this will give you all links in your html:

```
$html = file_get_contents($urlcontent);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$links = array();
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node)
    $links[] = $node->getAttribute('href');

print_r($links);
```

and if you want to get only links in table:

```
$html = file_get_contents($urlcontent);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$links = array();
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('table') as $table)
    foreach($table->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node){
        $href = $node->getAttribute('href');
        if(!in_array($href, $links))
            $links[] = $href;
    }

print_r($links);
```

Comment: I only want to get the links of the table

Answer (score 0):

You can apply some code like the following after lowercase html as string

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('/<a\s[^>]*href=\"([^\"]*)\"/', $url, $matches);
```